How to do a redirect after getting the result?
I am using ngrx in angular. I want to make it so that after loading an array of images redirection is performed.But I don't work redirection and get this error Error: Effect "CreateRequestEffects.uploadFile$" dispatched an invalid action: {}
    uploadFile$ = createEffect(() => {
        return this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(uploadFile),
            switchMap((action) => {
                return this.createRequestService.uploadFile(action.files, action.post_id).pipe(
                    takeUntil(
                        this.actions$.pipe(
                            ofType(UPLOAD_CANCEL)
                        ),
                    ),
                    map((data) => {
                        this.store$.dispatch(uploadFileSuccess({ image: data }))
                        return this.router.navigate([`/requests/post/${data[data.length].post_id}`]);
                    }),
                    catchError((err) => {
                        return of(err);
                    })
                );
            })
        )
    });


It seems like you want to redirect after the Success. As mat.hudak said before you need to return a action. You cant return a redirect. Your solution would be to do a redirect in a effect that listens to your uploadFileSuccess action. Something like this:


uploadFileSuccess$ = createEffect(() => 
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(uploadFileSuccesss),
            map((data) => {
                       this.router.navigate([`/requests/post/${data[data.length].post_id}`]);
                    })
        )
    ,{ dispatch: false });




NgRx effect should always return an action, if { dispatch: false } was not set. Which is your case. I believe this small change should be enough:
map((data) => {
  // Start navigation first
  this.router.navigate([`/requests/post/${data[data.length].post_id}`]);
  // Then return the success action
  return uploadFileSuccess({ image: data });
}),

